# Flutter Make Text Field go Up with keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, keyboard

I have a Text Field in the bottom Navigation Bar. I am making a chat screen, so when the User taps on the text field the keyboard go up, but the text field stick down and don't go up with. I tried many solutions but nothing worked, I am really stuck.
Flutter Version

> Flutter 1.26.0-1.0.pre

```dart
return  Scaffold(
     resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
     backgroundColor: Palette.primary,
     appBar: MyAppBar(),
     body: MyBody(),
     bottomNavigationBar: TextField(
               maxLength: 255,
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                 hintText: " write here",
                 focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 border: null,
                 hintStyle: GoogleFonts.getFont('Tajawal',
                     color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                 counterText: "",
               ),
               style: GoogleFonts.getFont('Tajawal',
                   fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
             ),
     ),

 );
}
}
```

[image: ScreenShot 1]

[image: ScreenShot 2]

Comment: Wrap your textfield with `Stack` widget and Set alignment to bottom and remove `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`,

Comment: @AR thank you, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is happening ?

Comment: nothing, same as the sceenshots.

Comment: Remove textfield from bottomNavigationbar and add in body

Comment: also the same as the screenshots. :(

Comment: have you tried singlechildscrollview?

Comment: the body have already a singlechildscrollview widget -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap your text field in listview 
set the reverse named parameter to true and after that call the `reversed` getter and run the `tolist` function

```
 ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'I move!',
              ),
            ),
          ].reversed.toList(),
        ),
```

### result:

[image]

whole code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: ' Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: new Color(0xFFFF0000),
      ),
      home: new FormDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class FormDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormDemoState createState() => _FormDemoState();
}

class _FormDemoState extends State<FormDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'I move!',
              ),
            ),
          ].reversed.toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i followed it step by step, but still the bottom navigation not moving up.

Comment: could you show me what happened with code above?

Comment: it did the same thing as the screenshots, nothing changed. btw if you can provide me a solution where the text field is in the body it wont matter, what does matter is that i need the text field fixed in the bottom.

Comment: you can put it in align widget with  `Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: TextField()
        ),`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by adding this part to the `textfield`, my problem was solved!

```
scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
```